# Can I run Nightwatch js in paralell with a different env per worker?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I'm currently using Nightwatch js to run my E2E tests in paralell.

The issue I'm having is that my tests share the same database, which is causing me problems with shared data being rewritten across different tests/workers, resulting in flaky tests.
I thought about running each test worker with its own database, but I'm not sure how to do it in practice. My starting point would be having different settings for the test databases, each on a night-watch env which can be accessed by the individual workers, but so far I've not found if this would be possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run different tests on different workers, Nightwatch provides a way to do that. I have done something very similar where I ran the same test on three different browsers parallely.

You have to add the `test_Worker` configuration, which allows the tests to be run in parallel. When this is enabled the test runner will launch a configurable number of child processes and then distribute the loaded tests over to run in parallel.

The workers option configures how many child processes can run concurrently.
a) “auto” – determined by the number of CPUs e.g. 4 CPUs means 4 workers
b) {number} – specifies an exact number of workers

```
test_workers: {
            enabled: true,
            workers: 'auto'
        }
```

This is how my `Nightwatch.conf.js` file looks like:

```
{
module.exports = {
    src_folders: ["tests"],
    test_settings: {
        default: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 4444,
                server_path: require('chromedriver').path,
            }
        },

        test_workers: {
            enabled: true,
            workers: 'auto'
        },

        safari: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'safari',
                alwaysMatch: {
                    acceptInsecureCerts: false
                }
            },
            webdriver: {
                port: 4445,
                start_process: true,
                server_path: '/usr/bin/safaridriver'
            }
        },

        firefox: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 4446,
                server_path: require('geckodriver').path
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to execute the test I use the command:

```
npx nightwatch tests/TC001_WikiSearch.js -e default,firefox,safari
```

Referenced from: https://testersdock.com/execute-parallel-tests-nightwatchjs/